# PHP simplexml_load_string include form field data

Tags: simplexml, php

i have a form on a PHP page. All i trying to do is parse out some XML entered into that form (COMMAND) using `simplexml_load_string` here is the test code:

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $Input = $_GET['COMMAND'];
        $Data =<<<XML
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> .
        $Input .XML;

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($Data);
        var_dump($xml); 
    }
        else
    }
        echo 'WTF!'
    }
?>

  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
    <textarea name="COMMAND" id="COMMAND" cols="45" rows="5">
        <API>
         <COMMAND>Test</COMMAND>
        </API>
   </textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

this is the error i am receiving:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/cgi/index.php on line 24

i think it has something to do with my weak attempt at concatenation.

Comment: thanks dave, i did fix that but it still didn't rid me of the error.

Comment: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 2):

You have a closing brace where you want an opening brace:

```
}
    else
}   // <- BAD!
    echo 'WTF!'
}
```

You want:

```
}
    else
{   // <- GOOD!
    echo 'WTF!'
}
```

This is a personal choice, but I'd recommend following the [PEAR standard](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) for PHP coding. Your code would appear as:

```
if (...) {
} else {
}
```

Makes it a lot easier to catch those evil braces!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what hobodave wrote you are missing a ; on your

```
echo 'WTF!';
```

line

Comment: You'll need to supply more code then if you want better debugging.  From what you showed us hobodave and I have pointed out the syntax errors.  But we don't know if you have a problem in another place.  Other than the syntax errors we've pointed out your supplied code looks good.